# Can I use a Neural Network to obtain an estimate of the output series, only knowing the input?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Let's say I have a model

h(t) = F[h(t-1),h(t-2), ... , u(t-1), u(t-2), ...]

where F[] is a non-linear function of the variables included in the function.

So for example, h(t) could be:

h(t) = h(t-1) + u(t-1) + h(t-1)*u(t-1) + h(t-1)*h(t-2)

Now, for the sake of my problem, I only have the data series u(t) available to me. I don't have a series for h(t) nor do I know the model.

Is it possible for me to use the Neural Network Toolbox to generate a good non-linear estimate of h(t) by just providing u(t)? If so, what neural network do I use?

Comment: I guess you meant "by just providing u(t)"?

Comment: To generate a good non-linear estimate of h(t) you'll need to compute the error between the estimate (i.e. the ANN's output) and the real value h(t). Since you don't have a series for h(t), I don't believe this problem is solvable.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is like teaching children multiplications without ever giving any hint what could be the right solution. You should at least be able to provide some kind of fitness function that estimates how good your ANN performs. Then you could use an evolutionary algorithm (e. g. CMA-ES) to optimize your ANN.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming (h(t-1), h(t-2), ...) is a time series. I'll call (h(t-1), h(t-2), ...) **time-series h** and (u(t-1), u(t-2), ...) **time-series u**. So you are fitting an ANN model with knowledge of a current value for h called **h(t)** and a previous historical time series for u (time-series u).

If you could find a function for **h(t)** without knowing the previous **h time-series** then you would not have a function of h(t-1), h(t-2), etc. Mathematically this would mean that you do not have a dependence on the historical values for h.

It is possible that for certain domains your model could accurately predict **h(t)** given values of **time-series u** only but I would not trust such a model given that:

1. you say that **h(t)** has a non-linear dependence on previous values for **h(t)** and
2. you mention **time-series h** in the first place

This leads me to believe that you will be using the model in domains where **time-series h** is important and because the model is non-linear the error can increase dramatically once you get outside your fitted region. Even worse, without knowledge of the **h time-series** you wont even know where the "good fit" region is.

If you had the model, there might be some tricky way to get the **h time-series** given **h(t)** and the **u time-series** but I don't think that is what you are asking.